# Visual C++ initialization inconsistence with gcc and clang

Tags: c++, visual-c++, initialization, c++14, list-initialization

The following piece of code [prints `0` compiled with *vc++*](http://rextester.com/OIG44494) and [prints `1` compiled with *g++* or *clang++*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d6828d3df14ab90):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct S
{
    S() = default;

    std::vector<int> v{0};        
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> s{{}};

    std::cout << s.front().v.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Is it a bug in *vc++*?

If a user-defined constructor is provided (`S() {};` instead of `S() = default;`) [*vc++* starts to print `1`, too](http://rextester.com/ADRHQ41270).

Comment: Looks indeed like a compiler bug in the vc++ compiler.

Comment: I seem to recall that there's an upcoming change in C++17 regarding a curly brace initializer with exactly one item. What happens if  you change the 0 to a 13?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf E.g. `std::vector<int> v{ 11,22 };` produces the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reading the Standard (C++11 n3485), `12.6.2/9` states that:

> If a given non-static data member has both a `brace-or-equal-initializer` and a `mem-initializer`, the initialization specified by the `mem-initializer` is performed, and the non-static data member’s `brace-or-equal-initializer` is ignored.

So the question becomes if the `default`, i.e. the implicitly defined constructor contains a `mem-initializer` or not.

Section `12.1/6` states:

> The implicitly-defined default constructor performs the set of initializations of the class that would be performed by a user-written default constructor for that class with no `ctor-initializer` (12.6.2) and an empty `compound-statement`.

This would mean the implicitly generated (default) constructor has no `mem-initializer`s and should indeed use the in-class initializer (the `brace-or-equal-initializer` in the above quote).

MSVC is wrong here (no surprise there, really).

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but a comment requiring code.

The following illustrates the compiler differences more clearly, I think:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct S
{
    S() = default;

    std::vector<int> v = std::vector<int>(13);
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> s{{}};
    std::cout << s.front().v.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Here g++ MinGW 5.1.0 reports 13 items, while MSVC 2015 update 2 reports 0 items.

I.e. g++ uses the initializer specified in the class, while MSVC uses the one specified in the declaration of `s`. To me that looks like a problem with g++. But I'm not sure: the only sure thing is that both can't be right.